# Deriving the limits of integrals

Tags: integration

I have this equation, $$\int_{R}\int_{}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$$ were R is a region in positive quadrant for which ($x+y \leq 1$). I want to know how do I derive the limits of x & y.

-Thanks,
Kamal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region is that in the first quadrant between the axes and the line $y=-x+1$ so doing this as a double integral with $y$ the outer integration the limits on the $y$ are $0$ and $1$ and $x$ the inner integration on the $x$ integral are $0$ and $1-y$. That is:
$$
\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^{1-y} x^2+y^2 \ dx\;dy
$$

Doing the integral the other way, $x$ outer then $y$, the limits on the $x$ integration are $0$ and $1$ and on the $y$ integration are $0$ and $1-x$